# Json Serializing extra properties using Refit Post

Tags: refit

I am trying to post using Refit and keep getting a 500 error. The Object that I am posting if I JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model) looks fine but when I pass the model into my Refit Interface I get the following: a 275 before and a 0 after the json:

```
275 { all my model properties } 0
```

**Heres my Refit Interface:**

```
[Post("/api/Url/{id})]
Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostModel([Body] Model model, string id);
```

When I debug I am able to see that the model and id are being passed correctly into the interface.